# Display two domain object values as one JSON output

Tags: json, grails

I am working on grails and I have a use case with two domain classes class A and class B which are independent classes.I want the class A and class B values in one JSON view.

```
class A                                                
String name,                                          
String age

class B
String report
```

In Bootstrap.groovy file i have written the below format to display the values in JSON view.

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(A) {it->
def result = [:]
result['name'] = it.name
result['age'] = it.age
result['report'] = it.report    //It throws an error no such property: report for class A.How to write it in a proper JSON format to retrieve the report value?

return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html#_builders)

> Groovy comes with integrated support for converting between Groovy
>   objects and JSON. The classes dedicated to JSON serialisation and
>   parsing are found in the groovy.json package.

For example you could use [groovy.json.JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html#_streamingjsonbuilder)

In your example you could try this

Having classes A and B

```
class A {
    String name
    String age
}

class B {
    String report
}
```

Import `JsonBuilder` in Bootstrap.groovy file

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
```

An then you can try

```
A a = new A(name: 'ana', age: '15')
B b = new B(report: 'lorem ipsum...')

JsonBuilder jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder()

jsonBuilder.result {
    name a.name
    age a.age
    report b.report
}

println jsonBuilder.toString()
```

Output

```
{"result":{"name":"ana","age":"15","report":"lorem ipsum..."}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more reusable code, then you can create a new class with public properties you want to show up in the json result.

```
class MyJSONResult(){
   String name
   String age
   String report
   // add more properties as needed

   // constructor
   MyJSONResult(A a, B b){
      name = a.name
      age = a.name
      report = b.report
   }
}

//when you need json result,
import grails.converters.JSON


def json = new MyJSONResult(a, b)
render json as JSON
```

The good thing about creating a new class and an object is that you can reuse it. For example if you needed to show the same result in the gsp page, you can pass the object to a view and access its properties.

```
def json = new MyJSONResult(a, b)
render view:'myview', model:[myVar: json]

// in gsp views
${myVar.name}
```

This way any business logic you used in building the json payload can be used for your api or anywhere else you may need to use them

Comment: Any other solution if i dont want to create anew class?